# TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, chakra-ui

I am getting this error on some older iPhones (like iPhone 7 and iPhone 10)

[image: TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function]

I am unable to find the solution.

**Libraries that I am using**

```
 "@chakra-ui/react": "^1.4.1",
    "@chakra-ui/theme-tools": "^1.1.7",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.2.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.11.0",
    "agora-rtc-sdk": "3.3.1",
    "agora-rtm-sdk": "1.4.1",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.828.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "browser-image-compression": "^1.0.14",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.3",
    "firebase": "^8.2.4",
    "framer-motion": "4.1.11",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "nanoid": "^3.1.20",
    "next": "^11.0.1",
    "next-cookies": "^2.0.3",
    "next-pwa": "^5.0.6",
    "nextjs-redirect": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-feather": "^2.0.9",
    "react-hot-toast": "^1.0.2",
    "react-image-magnify": "^2.7.4",
    "react-player": "^2.7.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-select": "^4.0.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "swiper": "^6.7.5",
    "use-http": "^1.0.18",
    "video.js": "^7.10.2",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
```

**Things I tried**

1. Upgrading NodeJS from Version 12 to Version 14.17.1 (But this did not help)

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling all the libraries?

Comment: [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) doesn't exist in the JS versions used in older browsers. You probably want to build your app using a polyfill for that function. Since you're using Next, you can probably follow their [docs on using polyfills](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/supported-browsers-features).

Comment: @Mack Thank you this pointed me in the right direction. I will add my specific solution as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was install the polyfill for `Object.fromEntries` and import it into the _app.tsx file.

1. [polyfill-object.fromentries](https://www.npmjs.com/package/polyfill-object.fromentries)